# How to get rid of Konsole toolbar

Tags: konsole

It happened to me after an update to Konsole.

How can I remove the icons in the red box below?

There is a `Show Menubar` checkbox on context menu, I'm wondering why lack of `Show toolbox` checkbox made such a pain in ass.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on toolbar
2. uncheck "lock this toolbar"
3. click on "toolbar shown"
4. Uncheck all the options there...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason KDE people removed modifing and removing option for toolbars. Earlier, toolbars could be removed from settings. But no worry, it can be still removed from run-control file for Konsole.

Modify these two files `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/sessionui.rc` and `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/konsoleui.rc`. They are simply XML.
Comment/delete the contents of <ToolBar> tags. There are three of them Main toolbar, session toolbar and another.

Demo:
Before

```
<ToolBar name="mainToolBar" noMerge="1" alreadyVisited="1"> 
   <text translationDomain="kxmlgui5">Main Toolbar</text> 
   <Action name="edit_find"/> 
   <Action name="file_print"/> 
  </ToolBar>
```

[image: Before modification]
After

```
<!-- <ToolBar name="mainToolBar" noMerge="1" alreadyVisited="1"> -->
   <!-- <text translationDomain="kxmlgui5">Main Toolbar</text> -->
   <!-- <Action name="edit_find"/> -->
   <!-- <Action name="file_print"/> -->
  <!-- </ToolBar> -->
```

[image: After modification]

Answer (score 0):

The recent problem in Archlinux (Plus open Konsole in Dolphin which doesn't work) is related to `konsole-21.08.0-1`. If you are lucky enough the earlier version is still in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/` which you can downgrade to:

```
sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/konsole-21.04.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```